# slideToggle stopped working in IE 9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9, slidetoggle

I've had no problems until I upgraded to IE 9.

Here is the javascript:

```
 jQuery.noConflict(); 
var $j = jQuery; 


$j(document).ready(function () {
    $j('div.menu_class').click(function () {
    $j('ul.the_menu').slideToggle('medium');
    });
});
```

Here is the html:

```
<div id="button" class="menu_class">
        <ul class="the_menu">
          <li><a href="/houston.html">Houston</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#button {
    height: 32px;
    width: 184px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image:  url(button.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    position:absolute;
    left: 499px;
    top: 71px;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:32px;
    z-index:1;
}
#button ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
}
.menu_class {
    border:1px solid #1c1c1c;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.the_menu {
    display:none;
    width:184px;
    border: 1px solid #1c1c1c;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:left;
    line-height:16px;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
    top:33px;
    left:0;
}
.the_menu li {
    background-color: #302f2f;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.the_menu li a {
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
}
.the_menu li a:hover {
    padding:10px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #F00880;
}
```

Any ideas on what the problem could be or how to fix it?

Thanks,

Tim

Answer (score 0):

sorry to reopen an old post!

I encountered this problem with IE9 too, the best solution I found was to actually apply the toggle to the LI instead of the UL, worked a charm!

Answer (score 0):

> Setting "position: relative; zoom: 1;" on the parent seems to fix the
>   problem.

- [JQuery Issue Ticket 11168](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11168)